# Is there a way to avoid the ad block and land on the Notion page without a server-side request (react-notion-x)

Tags: reactjs, notion

i use react-notion-x plugin

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch(`https://notion-api.splitbee.io/v1/page/${pageId}`)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    const blockMap = {};
    console.log('NOTION DATA : \n' + JSON.stringify(data));
    Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
      blockMap[key] = data[key];
    });
    setBlockMap(blockMap);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error('An error occurred: ' + err));
}, []);
```

but

[image]

Is there a way to avoid the ad block and land on the Notion page without a server-side request?